# How to convert a string to a multidimensional recursive array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, recursion

I have a problem with creating a recursive array with PHP.

I need to format this string to a multidimensional array with the dot-separated elements indicating multiple levels of array keys.

```
$str = "code.engine,max_int.4,user.pre.3,user.data.4";
```

The output for this example would be:

```
$str = array(
   "code" => "engine",
   "max_int" => 4,
   "user" => array(
      "pre" => 3,
      "data" => 4
   )
);
```

I will start with an `explode` function, but I don't know how to sort it from there, or how to finish the foreach.

Comment: Do you mean `user.data.4` instead of `users.data.4`?

Comment: @Alejandro I edited assuming `users.data.4` was a typo. If I was mistaken, you can re-edit, but if you do please also explain why that should generate the expected output.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37590590/2943403

Comment: Proof of dupe appropriateness: https://3v4l.org/HJeLh

Comment: Also Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9636021/2943403

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could start to split using comma `,`, then, split each item by dot `.`, remove the last part to get the "value", and the rest as "path". Finally, loop over the "path" to store the value:

```
$str = "code.engine,max_int.4,user.pre.3,user.data.4";

$array = [] ;
$items = explode(',',$str);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $parts = explode('.', $item);
    $last = array_pop($parts);

    // hold a reference of to follow the path
    $ref = &$array ;
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        // maintain the reference to current path 
        $ref = &$ref[$part];
    }
    // finally, store the value
    $ref = $last;
}
print_r($array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [code] => engine
    [max_int] => 4
    [user] => Array
        (
            [pre] => 3
            [data] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: FYI...  Works great without `if (!isset($ref[$part])) $ref[$part]=[];`

Comment: Oh, yes. Right @AbraCadaver. Thank you! But. humm... Why `$ref = &$ref[$part]` don't throw an _"undefined index"_?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Ok. That because of the reference. We can create a reference to an undefined value (https://3v4l.org/8pTaK).

Comment: I hadn't refreshed my window and didn't see your comment that you found it :-) _Note:

If you assign, pass, or return an undefined variable by reference, it will get created._ http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: @AlejandroGuevara You need something like this https://3v4l.org/TI3Wd ?